# Convert a HTML Collection to Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I am a newbie, trying to learn w3c-dom, html-dom, just went through this [DOM-Introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DOM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var getByTag = function(selector) {
        // FIXME: Do more conditions -- Come Up with more non-verbose regex condition
        return /\w/i.test(selector) ? document.getElementsByTagName(selector) : null;
      }
      var isHTMLCollection = function(data) {
        return data.toString() === '[object HTMLCollection]';
      }
      var toArray = function(c) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(c);
      }
      var getAllPs = getByTag('p');
      console.log(isHTMLCollection(getAllPs), 'isHTMLCollection');
      console.log(Array.isArray(getAllPs), 'isArray-1');
      console.log(getAllPs, 'getAllPs');
      var _arrayLike = toArray(getAllPs);
      console.log(Array.isArray(_arrayLike), 'isArray-2');
      console.log(_arrayLike.length, 'Array.length');
    </script>
    <p id="p1">
      First Para
    </p>
    <p id="p2">
      Second Para
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

While logging this on console, i got just an empty array, when i tried to convert the HTMLCollection to Array.

Note: Tried using for-loop also.

Attached the console output,

[image: Console-Chrome]

Comment: Your code will not work as it is looking for `<p>` tags _before_ the p tags are actually read by the DOM. Either move your script to below the `<p>` tags or wrap your code in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ ... })` - To show you: log `getAllPs.length`.

Comment: Should be noted that `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(selector))` does roughly the same thing

Comment: @adeneo Yes it does, but it instantiates a new object, which is technically a wasted resource.

Comment: @somethinghere  Can you see the console output HTMLCollection is printed on the console after that only i try to convert the collection to array.

Comment: The reason you see the objects in the console, is that console ouput is generated asynchronously, and by that time the live node list has already been updated. But your code completes before that time, and at that time the node list is still empty. You are being mislead by the console output.

Comment: What @trincot said. An HTMLCollection is live. Try logging `getAllPs.length` as your first console log and you will see it report `0`.

Comment: Unless you really need the "live" feature of the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) I would go with the new [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/querySelectorAll) method. It returns a "non-live" [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which wouldn't have produced this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adding

> document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //rest of the code });

fixes the issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DOM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var getByTag = function(selector) {
          // FIXME: Do more conditions -- Come Up with more non-verbose regex condition
          return /\w/i.test(selector) ? document.getElementsByTagName(selector) : null;
        }
        var isHTMLCollection = function(data) {
          return data.toString() === '[object HTMLCollection]';
        }
        var toArray = function(c) {
          return Array.prototype.slice.call(c);
        }
        var getAllPs = getByTag('p');
        console.log(isHTMLCollection(getAllPs), 'isHTMLCollection');
        console.log(Array.isArray(getAllPs), 'isArray-1');
        console.log(getAllPs, 'getAllPs');
        var _arrayLike = toArray(getAllPs);
        console.log(Array.isArray(_arrayLike), 'isArray-2');
        console.log(_arrayLike.length, 'Array.length');
      });
    </script>
    <p id="p1">
      First Para
    </p>
    <p id="p2">
      Second Para
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note: Problem with chrome console is, array values are evaluated on asynchronously.**

---

### Thanks to @somethinghere & @trincot.

---

Comment: Wooot! It's these kind of things that trip things up when you start (_What the f*ck is going on???? Aaaarrrrrggghhh!_), but once you found them and answered them you won't be fooled twice!

Comment: I would like to suggest that the answer is _not_ `document.addEventListener`, but specifically adding an event listener for the `DOMContentLoaded` **event**. Adding a `click` event, for example, won't make a difference nor solve your problem (well, it will, but it requires a click)

Comment: Corrected & Updated @somethinghere